# How to set ContentPresenter default content to Unset in WPF XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to display status icons in status bar. The icons are defined as ViewBox static resources and displayed via ContentPresenter style with DataTriggers.

I would like no icon displayed if none of the triggers are matched, so I've tried setting the default Setter Content to `x:Null` or an empty string or remove the line at all, but the other icons stop displaying at all then.

Any ideas please?

My XAML code is as follows

```
<StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2">
    <ContentPresenter>
        <ContentPresenter.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="Ok">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource StatusOK}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="Invalid">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource StatusInvalid}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="Warning">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource StatusWarning}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentPresenter.Style>
    </ContentPresenter>
</StatusBarItem>
```

**Update**

I've tried using visibility as suggested by Ed Plunkett but the icons stopped showing up at all. Here is the code.

```
<Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource StatusOK}"/>
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="Ok">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource StatusOK}"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="Invalid">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource StatusInvalid}"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="Warning">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource StatusWarning}"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Why not set its visibility to Hidden instead?

Comment: I've tried setting visibility in the default setter and toggle it in the triggers but none of the icons show up then even with some icon defiend in the default setter.

Comment: Show me just what you did with that.

Comment: Check the Update section of the question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was misusing a ContentPresenter. There's no reason to use a ContentPresenter outside of a `ControlTemplate`. The only features it has which differ from `ContentControl` are things that only make sense inside a `ControlTemplate`. Now, as it happens, `StatusBarItem` is a subclass of `ContentControl`, so you could just style the `StatusBarItem` and set its `Content`. Either version in your question will work that way.

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea of simply replacing `ContentPresenter` with `ContentControl` in my code and suprisingly it works! Without any default Setter, Visibility property, DataTemplates or ControlTemplates. Just the style set. I'm quite new to WPF programming. Is it a good practice to do it like so?

Comment: @yaugenka There’s no harm in it; it’s just that the ContentControl is unnecessary, since its direct parent is also a type of ContentControl. The first thing I tried was just what you did, then I cleaned it up and generalized it.

Comment: I think it would make sense when there are several controls within one StatusBarItem, e.g. wrapped with a StackPanel.

Comment: @yaugenka Yes, If you had several controls would have to have a parent that can contain multiple controls.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ed